# Is it possible to reconstruct data from non stored field in lucene?

Tags: elasticsearch, encryption, solr, lucene

Let's say I have a set of addresses with uuid as the id. None of the fields except the id are stored in the index (indexed, but not stored). Is it actually possible to recreate the data with just the index file?

The problem is I have a set of encrypted data, but I want to be able to search them. Is it actually secure to index those data with lucene? If someone get their hands on the index file, will they be able to construct the data back?

Comment: how are those data analyzed when indexing them? Also, how to you intend to search, on the encrypted bits themselves?

Comment: let's just assume it's ngram or shingle. I intent to search using plaintext. For the result, it's enough to just have an id back.

Answer (score 2):

So:

1. you have a field X
2. you are not storing (and of course you are not using docvalues either)
3. you are indexing it with say, WhitespaceTokenizer and ShingleFilter

Then, in this case someone can reconstruct the original contents of the field. Ot at least 'mostly the original contents'. For instance all the whitespaces are lost, so they cannot know whether there were 1 or 5 spaces between two terms, but they will get the terms (I assume that is the important part).

If you were using a NGramTokenizer/NGramTokenFilter, the same applies, they would get the chance to reconstruct the important terms.

By the way, there is [a patch here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6966) that proposes to implement field level encryption, but was never committed. You might be interested in looking in there.